Как обслуживать статический контент с помощью Node.js(Express js) без использования шаблонизатора?
Есть простой сервер на Express и  статическая страница с формой (ввод имени и возраста), могу ли добавить таблицу с данными пользователя на эту же страницу после отправки формы, но без использования шаблонизаторов? Я попробовал как здесь https://metanit.com/web/nodejs/4.11.php, но ничего не вышло, даже после полного копирования кода. Ниже прикреплю фото того, чего хочу добиться


Ну не используйте шаблонизаторов. HTML это просто строка. Сформируйте её любым способом.

В том то и дело что не могу), я эксперимента ради скопировал весь представленный на сайте код к себе, но ничего не вышло, не знаю как это сделать,

А подскажите что конкретно не получается получить данные или у вас может в консоле есть ошибки?

Ох, если бы в консоли была ошибка, дело в том, что просто ничего не происходит, да, в массив добавляется пользователь и консоль его можно вывести, но я хочу именно появления и обновления  таблицы под формой. Я конечно полный ноль в js, но мне кажется что код по ссылке, которую я указал выше, просто не рабочий(надеюсь я ошибаюсь), может у вас есть пример рабочего кода?
